# Do Strong Jaw and Improved Natural Attack stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats

I have seen quite a bit of debate about whether or not Strong Jaw and Improved Natural Attack stack with each other. Do they or don't they, and why?

Comment: Duplicate of [Stacking size damages](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89873/stacking-size-damages)

Comment: @WeirdFrog I'm hesitant to close this as, usually, a question asking about a specific interaction between two effects is left open even when a question addresses the broader general interaction, but I'll leave closure to the community.

Comment: much more specific case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Officially, [Improved Natural Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/improved-natural-attack/) and [*strong jaw*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/strong-jaw/) can't combine for a cumulative effect

The *Pathfinder Core Rulebook* [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm) includes this [exchange](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9t5u):

> #### *Size increases and effective size increases:* How does damage work if I have various effects that change my actual size, my effective size, and my damage dice?
>
> As per the rules on size changes, **size changes do not stack**, so if you have multiple size changing effects (for instance an effect that increases your size by one step and another that increases your size by two steps), only the largest applies. **The same is true of *effective* size increases** (**which includes** “**deal damage *as if* they were one size category larger than they actually are**,” “your damage die type increases by one step,” and similar language). They don’t stack with each other, just take the biggest one. However, you can have one of each and they do work together (for example, [*enlarge person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/) increasing your actual size to Large and a [*bashing*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/bashing/) shield increasing your shield’s effective size by two steps, for a total of 2d6 damage).

(Emphases and links in the exchange's reply mine.) The feat [Improved Natural Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/improved-natural-attack/) increases the damage of one of a creature's [natural attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#TOC-Natural-Attacks) "*as if* the creature’s size had increased by one category." The spell [*strong jaw*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/strong-jaw/) says, "Each natural attack that creature makes deals damage *as if* the creature were two sizes larger than it actually is." (Emphasis in both effects' quotations mine.)

As *both* the feat *and* the spell are *effective* size increases that use language nearly identical to that used in the FAQ, their effects don't stack.

Threads arguing about the interaction between these two effects may have been created before March 2015 when this exchange was added to the FAQ.